# Tab on Expect String concatenation

Tags: string, expect, concatenation

I'm kinda a novice on Expect, but I can't get over a problem I have with a logging-monitoring script i'm writing.

I've spent hours googling on why I can't get this to work:

```
puts $redirect [concat "${time}\t" "${context}\t" "$id\t" "${eventtype}" "${eventstatus}\t" "${eventcontext}" ]
```

The **\t** char ( it does not work even with other \chars ) is not showing up. No matter how and where I place it, I've tried different stuff:

```
puts $redirect [concat "${time}" "\t" "${context}"  [...] ]
puts $redirect [concat "${time}\t" "${context}" [...] ]
puts $redirect [concat "${time}" "\t${context}" [...] ]
puts $redirect [concat "${time}" \t "${context}" [...] ]
```

*where redirect is `set redirect [open $logfile a]`

*where [...] are other strings I'm concatenating, in the same way.

From http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10

> [5] Argument expansion.
>       If a word starts with the string “{*}” followed by a non-whitespace character, then the leading “{*}” is removed and the
>   rest of the word is parsed and substituted as any other word. After
>   substitution, the word is parsed as a list (without command or
>   variable substitutions; backslash substitutions are performed as is
>   normal for a list and individual internal words may be surrounded by
>   either braces or double-quote characters), and its words are added to
>   the command being substituted. For instance, “cmd a {*}{b [c]} d
>   {*}{$e f "g h"}” is equivalent to “cmd a b {[c]} d {$e} f "g h"”.
>
> [6] Braces.
>       If the first character of a word is an open brace (“{”) and rule [5] does not apply, then the word is terminated by the matching close
>   brace (“}”). Braces nest within the word: for each additional open
>   brace there must be an additional close brace (however, if an open
>   brace or close brace within the word is quoted with a backslash then
>   it is not counted in locating the matching close brace). No
>   substitutions are performed on the characters between the braces
>   except for backslash-newline substitutions described below, nor do
>   semi-colons, newlines, close brackets, or white space receive any
>   special interpretation. The word will consist of exactly the
>   characters between the outer braces, not including the braces
>   themselves.

Ironically, I can get this to work:

```
puts $redirect [concat "${time}\n" "-\t${context}" [...] ]
```

If I put a char before the TAB, it works, but I can't use it.

Ex output: `2016-06-01 15:43:12 -    macro`

Wanted output: `2016-06-01 15:43:12    macro`

I've tried on building the string with `append` but it's like it is eating pieces of string due to max buffer char, is it possible?

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: How is `append` failing? Is there a reason you were tying to use `concat` here instead of just a long string literal with all the variables in it `${time}\t${context}\t$id\t${eventtype}${eventstatus}\t${eventcontext}`?

Comment: An example output of `append` is:

2016-06HANGUPNAVomain-1JUniqueId=JustSrvDomain-1464793190.747&HangupCause=16e=Hangup&SphereGroup=&NextSphereName=hangup 2016-06-01 17:00:0058ledNum=13666 2016-06-01 16:59:55


It's messed up, it puts the time at the end, the context is nowhere, "omain-1" is a part of $id and on.. , I did use the string you provided me on this one.

Comment: That almost looks like you have carriage return characters (`\r`) in the values so the output (to the terminal) is overwriting itself (or something similar with tcl). Are you sure the strings contain exactly the values you expect?

Comment: I was looking for that too at the moment, the last log i got it repeated the '$time' like 3 times and a "\t" worked.

`[..] phereName=hangup 2016-06 2016-06-01 17:17:58     2016-06-01 17:17:52`

Thanks for giving me an idea! Gonna let you know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what `concat` does. It eats whitespace.

From the documentation for [`concat`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/concat.htm):

> This command joins each of its arguments together with spaces after trimming leading and trailing white-space from each of them. If all the arguments are lists, this has the same effect as concatenating them into a single list. It permits any number of arguments; if no args are supplied, the result is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

@Etan gave you why it's not working for you.

An alternate way to code that is to use [`format`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm)

```
puts $redirect [format "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s%s\t%s" $time $context $id $eventtype $eventstatus $eventcontext]
```